# HTTP authentification in JSF 1.2 on Websphere

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I'm using JSF 1.2 + Tomahawk 1.1.13 on Webshere 7.0

My web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/search.faces</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Websphere Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Default</web-resource-name>
        <description />
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

my login.jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">

    <jsp:include page="head.jsp" />

    <t:panelGrid columns="2" border="1"
        columnClasses="unfixedCol,fixedCol"
        style="style=text-align:top; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">

        <t:panelGroup>
            Login
        </t:panelGroup>
        <t:panelGroup>
            <h:inputText id="j_username" autocomplete="off" size="20" />
        </t:panelGroup>

        <t:panelGroup>
            Password
        </t:panelGroup>
        <t:panelGroup>
            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" autocomplete="off" size="20" />
        </t:panelGroup>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <t:panelGroup colspan="4"
                style="text-align:right; background-color:#d9e2f2;">
                <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" /> &nbsp; 
                <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
            </t:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

    </t:panelGrid>

    <jsp:include page="foot.jsp" />

</form>
```

When i acsess /localhost:9080/App/, and enter correct credentials, all seems ok, i log in, but this works with problems:

1. I can access to application jsp-pages without security check (i can access /localhost:9080/App/search.jsp without check, but when i accesss /localhost:9080/App/ - there is security-check). Tried different url-patterns.
2. When i try to get HTTP-session user with FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal() - there is always null, all the time, when i loged id. why?

Checked all guides, include some stackowerflow questions and didn't realise, what my problem is in.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

For our application we have defined like:

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

and since we have integrated LDAP authentication as well so we have created custom `application-policy` and specified in `realm`

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>OUR_AUTH_NAME_DEFINED_IN_login-config.xml</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp?invalidUser=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Hope this helps!!!